# Question about proving a function on linear space to be norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ denote the linear space of all polynomials in one variable with coefficients in $\mathbb{K}$. (Where   $\mathbb{K}$ denotes $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$). For $p \in X$ with $p(t) = a_0 + a_1t + ....+a_nt^n$, let $$||p||= sup\{|p(t)|:0 \leq t  \leq 1 \}$$
I have proved all other properties for $||p||$ being a norm on this space except $$||p|| = 0 \implies p=0$$
I need help with the above part.

Comment: If $\lVert p\rVert = 0$, then $p$ vanishes on the interval $[0,1]$. Hence it has infinitely many zeros. But $p$ is a polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$$||p||=\sup_{0\leq t\leq 1}\{|p(t)|\}=0$$
then 
$$|a_0+a_1t+\ldots+a_nt^n|=0\,,\quad \forall\,t\in[0,1]$$
In particular, the above holds for $t=0$
$$|a_0+a_1\cdot 0+\ldots+a_n\cdot 0^n| = |a_0|=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad a_0=0$$
Thus,
$$|a_1t+a_2t^2+\ldots+a_nt^n|= |t||a_1+a_2t+\ldots+a_nt^{n-1}| =0\,,\quad \forall\,t\in[0,1]$$
Again, as the above holds for every $t\in[0,1]$, then
$$|a_1+a_2t+\ldots+a_nt^{n-1}| =0\,,\quad \forall\,t\in[0,1]$$
In particular, again the above holds for $t=0$, then
$$|a_1+a_2\cdot 0+\ldots+a_n\cdot 0^n| = |a_1|=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad a_1=0$$
Inductively, you get to prove that $a_j=0$ for all $j\in\{0,1,\ldots, n\}$, therefore, $p=0$.